# How to connect hotkey with the discord mute hot key and simultaniously make an image appear

Tags: discord, autohotkey

This is my first question so I hope that I'm following the guide lines.

A friend of mine streams and is having problems with his discord mute Button. He mutes himself to not disturb the people in the call so he can answer a question in his chat,
but than he forgets to unmute and doesn't talk for a few minutes. So I thought that I could give him a surprise and make it that when he mutes himself, an image appears on his display, that tells him that he is muted.
But when doing that the the discord mute button doesn't activate, so I need ahk to activate the discord mute button and make the image appear. The image is done. But the muting part is really hard to do.
It just won't mute him. If it's possible I don't want to change the initial hot key of control+b, which is his setting.
Below is the Code. Thank you very much.

```
ShowIcon = 1

Gui, Add, Picture, w36 h-1 , MicMute.png

Gui, +Owner

Gui, +AlwaysOnTop

Gui -Caption

Gui, Show, W300 H300 X1600 Y50

Gui, Color, EEAA99
Gui +LastFound
WinSet, TransColor, EEAA99



^b::
ControlSend, , {Control}1{b}, ahk_exe Discord.exe

    If ShowIcon = 0
    {
        Gui +LastFound
        Gui, Show, NA
        ShowIcon = 1
    }
    else
    {
        Gui, +LastFound
        Gui, Hide
        ShowIcon = 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a hotkey in AutoHotkey, by default it assumes you want to intercept that hotkey before it performs its native function.  In this case, you actually want the hotkey to fire your function **and** still fire the native function.  AutoHotkey is way ahead of you: it's got a special hotkey modifier that specifies that AutoHotkey should **not** intercept the native function of the hotkey.  Just stick a `~` in front of your hotkey, like so:

```
~^b::
    ; Your code here
    Return
```

The documentation for this is [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols).

Comment: Thank you very much, I struggled with this for so long. It now works as I intend it to be